# Where do I find backgrounds like this?

Tags: website-design, background

I saw this shot uploaded to Dribbble some weeks ago. And I really like the use of the backgrounds. Does anyone know where I can find backgrounds like it? I want ones with something like mountains or maybe buildings in bottom of the image, and then the rest is like sky or a blurred image. Just ones that's really good for web- and graphic design use.

Shot:

https://dribbble.com/shots/1929614-Qianxun-Website/attachments/332195

Thanks.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as we have numerous questions about finding high quality photos. Is that what you're looking for? Many of these had some level of editing done combining a few photos - do you want photos or finished wallpapers? You should also say what you've tried as far as searches go, so it looks like you put forth effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this backgrounds where done by combining various images on Photoshop.
There are loads of great free stock image webstes, I usually use [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/) and on the search tools select "free for commercial use" or [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/) that has beautiful free stock backgrounds. ***Bare in mind your examples where enhanced in Photoshop!***

Comment: Thanks! I knew that they probably used photoshop to create the images. I was just wondering how they got the images used to create it. And you answered that perfectly.